# Reverse redirecting and parsing a variable in Django

Tags: django-views, httpresponse, http-redirect, django-1.11

I have a function in view whereby given the triggering of variable to True, the user is redirected to a different page:

```
def first_function(request):
    if settings.TRIGGER:        
        with transaction.atomic(): 
            if not order_lock.can_edit(request.user): 
                is_locked = not order_lock.can_edit(request.user) 
                from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(some_function))
            else:
                is_locked = False
                order_lock.lock_edit(request.user)



    def some_function(request):
        orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('status','created')

        return render(
            request,
            'myapp/index.html',
            {
                'orders': orders,
            },
        )
```

The problem is I've tried various permuations of parsing the variable `is_locked` into the `return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse(some_function))`
but to no avail, so that my `some_function` is adapted to:

```
    def some_function(request, is_updated=None):
        orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('status','created')

        return render(
            request,
            'myapp/index.html',
            {
                'orders': orders,
                'is_updated': is_updated,
            },
        )
```

Is there a way to resolve this so that the `is_updated` variable can be parsed upon a reverse redirect? The intention is to trigger off in the html (due to the is_updated) a pop up that notifies the user.

EDIT:

**view.py**

```
def edit_order(request, id = None, order_id = None)
    with transaction.atomic():
        order_lock = get_object_or_404(Order.objects.select_for_update(), id=id)
        if not order_lock.can_edit(request.user): 
            is_locked = not order_lock.can_edit(request.user) 
            from django.shortcuts import redirect
            from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
            return redirect(idx_order, kwargs={'is_locked': is_locked}) # Use this when url matter is resolved


def idx_order(request, is_locked=None):
    orders = Order.objects.all().order_by('status','deadline','created','lastUpdate').exclude(status=2)
    return render(
        request,
        'myapp/index_pimped.html',
        {
            'is_locked': is_locked
        },
    )
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^$', idx_order, name='idx_order'), # This works fine....
#url(r'^(?P<is_locked>[-\w]+)/$', idx_order, name='idx_order'), # ...but this doesn't
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code
you need

```
url(r'^result/(?P<result>[^\/]*)/$', views.result, name='result'),
```

and

```
return redirect(reverse('many:result', kwargs={ 'result': result }))
```

or (without changing url)

```
return redirect('/result/?p=%s' % result )
```

How about using redirect.

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def computer(request):
    result =  Computer.objects.order_by('?')[:1]
    return redirect('view-name-you-want', { 'result'=result })
```

Comment: how would you resolve this using my example above particularly with the same parameter names?